# Boot to shell - RHEL7

Tags: rhel, boot, systemd

According to this https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Terminal_Menu_Editing_During_Boot.html#sec-Booting_to_the_Debug_Shell

to `activate the debug shell only for this session, proceed as follows:`
 add `systemd.debug-shell` at the end of the `linux16` line after pressing `e` at the GRUB menu.

However, this doesn't do anything for me. It just continues straight to Level 5 (the GUI).

FWIW, I just have the following `shell` related lines in `dmesg`:

```
$ dmesg | grep shell
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quiet LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 systemd.debug-shell
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quiet LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 systemd.debug-shell
```

Any idea why I'm not booting to a shell?

Answer (score 3):

Adding the `systemd.debug-shell` kernel command-line parameter is not intended to prevent booting the system to a GUI (if one is installed). It just means that a debug shell is created.

To access the debug shell from the GUI, use **Ctrl+Alt+F9**.

More detailed instructions are provided in that same guide you're linking to, just a bit below the part you pasted into your question. See **Procedure 24.3. Connecting to the Debug Shell**.